# How can I make a jquery $.when statement refire if it fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So sometimes due to some kind of server asynchronicity issue, or something.. I don't know what, but it only happens every once in a while (s_mcir_2 calls its own AJAX functions that are cross-domain, so the other server I suppose can be unreliable)..  Anyway, every once in a while result is returned from s_mcir_2 as null instead of a JSON object.

When this happens, I would like to test if it is null, and then if it is, have the $.when statement refire.. theoretically until it receives valid output.

Any ideas?

```
$.when(s_mcir_2(alt, data[l_alt])).then(function(result) {
     //EVALUATE "result"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Deferred objects can only resolve once.

Try using a named function that calls itself on fail.

```
function myFn () {
  $.when(s_mcir_2(alt, data[l_alt])).then(function(result) {
    //EVALUATE "result"
    if (!result) {
      setTimeout(myFn,125);
      log("R_MCIR_2 has failed");
    }
    else {
      // success, do stuff
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have left out the .fail, it does not fire when result is returned as null. In fact it has yet to fire. My apologies.

Comment: I updated my answer. It's kindof odd that .fail() doesn't get triggered when a json response is returned as null. I guess it depends on what s_mcir_2 is doing.

Answer (score 1):

`.then()` can take two callback functions, one for `done` and one for `fail`. If you run your code inside a function you can recursively re-run your AJAX request (note that this could create an infinite loop):

```
var failedCount = 0;
function some_func() {
    $.when(s_mcir_2(alt, data[l_alt])).then(

    //done callback
    function(result) {
        //EVALUATE "result"
    },

    //fail callback
    function () {
        failedCount++;
        if (failedCount < 10) {
            //try again
            some_func();
        }
    });
}
```

Docs for `.then()`: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then

This code assumes that the `s_mcir_2()` function returns a jqXJR object (e.g. `return $.ajax(...)`).

Notice I added a counter to the failed function so this process won't continue infinitely. Once 10 requests have been made, the recursiveness stops.

**UPDATE**

If instead of the `jqXHR` object being rejected, if it is resolving to `success` you can check the server response and if it is null (e.g. `typeof(serverResponse) == 'null'`) then re-run the `some_func()` function.

Comment: How do I access the serverResponse?

Comment: @durangotango the server response is the first parameter in the `then` done-callback functions. I put the `result` variable as a parameter of the function to show you. The second parameter (if you want to use it) is a string that says how the request resolved (e.g. "success").

Answer (score 0):

```
function attempt(){
    $.when(s_mcir_2(alt, data[l_alt])).then(function(result) {
         //EVALUATE "result"
    }).fail(function(result) {
        log("R_MCIR_2 has failed");
        setTimeout(attempt,500)
    });
}
```